# How can download my viz from Tableau Public with a higher resolution?

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to download a viz from Tableau Public. The background of it I have designed in Figma. When I export the image from Figma to PNG, the background image has a very good resolution, but then when I use it in Tableau Public, it loses resolution when downloading it as an image, pdf or power point.